# Python multiplication of two list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and noticed that the following.

```
>>> 'D'*1
'D'
```

Therefore i wonder whether we can do multiplication and join the string (for choice, element can be 0 or 1 only)

```
>>> print(choice)
[1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> print(A)
['D', 'e', '0', '}']
```

My desired output would be `'De0}'`

Comment: What would print if `choice=[1,1,1,2]`?

Comment: there is another issue. my scenrio is that i would like to let the user to have a checkbox. if the item is checked, then 1, 0 otherwise. Therefore only 0 or 1 in this case.

Comment: @useR: in that case, you shouldn't really need to multiply here; just use 'compression'; pick elements or ignore them based on the truth value of the elements in `choice`.

Comment: terribly sorry that i didnt state my problem clearly, as i would like to do random.shuffle for A first and then join the element.

Comment: @useR: then do so? Or should `choice` be shuffled *along* with `A`? That's really a *separate* problem however. It doesn't matter if `A` is shuffled or not, because you should focus on the distinct problem you presented here: how to select items in one list based on the value of another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can explicity zip the lists, mulitply and then join the result:

```
''.join([c * i for c, i in zip(A, choice)])
```

The [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) pairs up the characters from `A` with the integers from `choice`, the list comprehension then multiplies the character with the integer, and the [`str.join()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) combines the result of that into one string.

If `choice` is used **just** used to *select* elements, you are better of using [`itertools.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) here:

```
from itertools import compress

''.join(compress(A, choice))
```

`compress()` does exactly what you were intending to do: pick elements from the first iterable based on wether or not the corresponding value in the second iterable is true or false.

Demo:

```
>>> choice = [1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> A = ['D', 'e', '0', '}']
>>> ''.join([c * i for c, i in zip(A, choice)])
'De0}'
>>> choice = [0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> ''.join([c * i for c, i in zip(A, choice)])
'e}'
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> ''.join(compress(A, choice))
'e}'
```

Using `itertools.compress()` is the *far faster* option here:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import random
>>> A = [chr(random.randrange(33, 127)) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> choice = [random.randrange(2) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> def with_mult(A, choice):
...     return ''.join([c * i for c, i in zip(A, choice)])
... 
>>> def with_compress(A, choice):
...     return ''.join(compress(A, choice))
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('f(A, choice)', 'from __main__ import A, choice, with_mult as f', number=10000)
1.0436905510141514
>>> timeit.timeit('f(A, choice)', 'from __main__ import A, choice, with_compress as f', number=10000)
0.2727453340048669
```

That's a 4x speed increase.

Comment: And of course we can also do it with a generator expression: `''.join(c * i for c, i in zip('De0}', [1, 1, 1, 0]))`

Comment: @PM2Ring see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/3005188 for why it's better to use a list comprehension as opposed to a generator expression when using `str.join`.

Comment: @PM2Ring: but a generator expression *with a `str.join()` call* is slower, because the `str.join()` has to have a list object to do two scans on (one to determine the total size, one to build the actual string).

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). See below for an example:

```
choice = [1, 1, 1, 0]
A = ['D', 'e', '0', '}']

out = ''.join([n*c for n, c in zip(choice, A)])

print(out)
# De0
```

As the 4th element of choice is 0 the 4th element of `A` ('}') is not printed.